# Get Firestore document key with Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've got the following code from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#-readme-tab-, but I'm not sure how to get each document's key. What I want to do is tap on each term to view or got to an edit page.

Firestore data model:

```
-content
--sPuJxAJu0dBMZLBTakd4
---term
---body content
```

Code:

```
class _TermsState extends State<Terms> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('content').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');

        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Text('Loading...');
          default:
            return ListView(
              children:
                  snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                print(document['term']);
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(document['term']),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html), you can use `document.documentID` to get its **key** and `document.reference.path` to get *the whole path*.

- [`DocumentSnapshot.documentID`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/documentID.html)
- [`DocumentSnapshot.reference`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/reference.html) returns the `DocumentReference` for this snapshot, which can be used to (also) get the `documentID` and also the complete `path` of the document.
- [`DocumentReference.documentID`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/documentID.html)
- [`DocumentReference.path`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/path.html)

In this case `document` is an object of type `DocumentSnapshot`, which you already retrieve correctly.

Answer (score 0):

An update to the above answer from `creativecreatorormaybenot`, the document ID can now be found in `document.id` from `DocumentSnapshot`. `document.documentID` will not return the id.

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540941/the-getter-documentid-isnt-defined-for-the-type-documentreference) to the answer I found