# The getter 'documentID' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentReference'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
CollectionReference itemsReference =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('items');
itemsReference.snapshots().forEach((snapshot) {
  snapshot.docs.forEach((documentSnapshot) {
    products.add(new Product(
      name: documentSnapshot.data()['name'],
      price: double.parse("${documentSnapshot.data()['price']}"),
      documentId: documentSnapshot.reference.documentID,// The getter 'documentID' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentReference'.
      description: documentSnapshot.data()['description'],
      image: documentSnapshot.data()['image'],
      imageCount: documentSnapshot.data()['image_count'],
      sellerEmail: documentSnapshot.data()['seller'],
      category: documentSnapshot.data()['category'],
      location: documentSnapshot.data()['location'],
      verified: documentSnapshot.data()['verified'],
    ));
```

I'm getting an error in line 8 in "documentID: documentSnapshot.reference.documentID," the Cloud Firestore version that I'm using is 0.16.0+1.

Comment: use documentSnapshot.id for getting document id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the API documentation for [DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html).  The property you're looking for is called [id](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/id.html).  There is no property `documentID` in modern versions of the SDK.